# ahk WinMove not working in a faster machine

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, script, autohotkey

is it possible that in a faster machine AHK WinMove feature does not working and needs something else?
I'm positive that the same script works in other slower computers, that means arrange my screens at the desire places, but that is not working at all with a x64 PC

```
Run c:\Users\NP\Documents\test.docx
       WinWait test.docx
       WinMove,ahk_class OpusApp,,-79,0,623,1023
       WinActivate ahk_class OpusApp
 Return
```

Comment: Can you post the script here so if anyone can test it on their computers to see if it works?

Comment: I saw that my problem is not with all windows but with special programs like MS Word, iSilo, and others I think PDF, I think that it is related to the way the application is being opened had it not added any special reference for an area at the screen. I think the problem is that the WinWait is too weak.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm to the top of you script

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
```